# Putting 2 different data values, where the data comes from serial port, into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, serial-communication

I have an hardware which sends the Temperature and Humidity values in a row via serial port. For example (25 celcicus degree and 47% humidity);

```
25
47
25
47
```

so it keeps sending like this.

And I'm receiving these values using this code:

```cs
data = serialPort.ReadLine();
```

`data` variable changes its value every receive cycle. And I want to keep these values in an array and refresh them. First value (temperature) must be in the array with the index of 0 and same for second value (humidity) with the index of 1. `data_array[0]` must be `25` and `data_array[1]` must be `47`.

Is there any way to do it?

**Edit_1**

One more question I want to ask. I want to write these values to a text box's text. For example; when I try `textBox_Temp.Text = data_array[0].ToString();` it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to read in two number in serial each time, why not simply read two inputs?

```
   data_array[0] = serialPort.ReadLine();
   data_array[1] = serialPort.ReadLine();
```

where data_array is a simple `int[] data_array = new int[2];`

I am sure you have a loop to keep reading these values. Initialize the data_array outside of the loop and update values in serial each time.

Comment: Thank you at first. It worked.

Now how can I write these different values into different TextBoxes' texts.

Comment: That was supposed to be = sign.. my bad. You can assign the value of ```data_array[0].ToString()``` to a ```textBox.Text```. please mark the post as answered if this helped with your question

Comment: ı tried `textBox_Temp.Text = data_array[0].ToString();` and gave an error like this `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation is not valid: The' txtBox_temperature 'control was accessed from another thread other than the thread from which it was created.'`.

Comment: thats a different question and not sure how you can update the fields of a UI while reading in the values in a different method.

Comment: `textBox.Temp.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { textBox.Temp.Text = data_array[0].ToString(); }));` made no error and it's working currently.